# How do I make nss_ldap ldap.conf file respsect a nss_base_passwd filter with multiple filters?

Tags: ldap

I've got a configuration on my machines using ldap where I want to have mod_nss getting users from two different filters

basically, I need to combine these two filters so I can get one list,

```
nss_base_passwd    ou=People,dc=remote,dc=my_company,dc=net?sub?entryDN=uid=*,ou=my_company,ou=people,dc=remote,dc=my_company,dc=net 

nss_base_passwd    ou=People,dc=remote,dc=my_company,dc=net?sub?entryDN=uid=*,ou=your_company,ou=people,dc=remote,dc=my_company,dc=net
```

each server I deploy has a different "your_company" on it and I need each machine to list users from my company and your company

If I do an ldapsearch like

```
ldapsearch -x "(|(entryDN=uid=*,ou=my_company,ou=people,dc=remote,dc=my_company,dc=net)(entryDN=uid=*,ou=your_company,ou=people,dc=remote,dc=my_compnay,dc=net))"
```

it retrieves the desired results, but placing that filter in nss_ldap doesn't work.

---

I think I'm getting this error in the access log, but not sure if it is relevant:

> [02/May/2019:14:19:39.038391111 -0500] conn=202 op=-1 fd=65 closed error 34 (Numerical result out of range) - B2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was easy, probably didn't need to post the question that I figured out the answer to 3 seconds later, but

```
nss_base_passwd    ou=People,dc=remote,dc=my_company,dc=net?sub?
|(entryDN=uid=*,ou=my_company,ou=people,dc=remote,dc=my_company,dc=net)(entryDN=uid=*,ou=your_company,ou=people,dc=remote,dc=my_compnay,dc=net)
```

did the trick, just needed to remove the parentheses around the filter, it looks like the parentheses are necessary in ldapsearch or else you get a

> ldap_search_ext: Bad search filter (-7)

but not needed for the nss_ldap filter